# Почему происходит ошибка mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'apache'@'localhost' (using password: NO)?

Tags: php, mysql, linux, apache, mysqli

Пытаюсь подсоединится к БД через root, пользователя БД, во всех слуаях вываливается ошибка:

```
mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'apache'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Через phpmyadmin все ок, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: вставьте, пожалуйста, фрагмент кода, осуществляющего подключение. внести исправления в вопрос можно, нажав [edit].

Comment: Это подключение через фреймворк Kohana 3.3

Comment: значит, должен быть некий конфигурационный файл, в котором указано, что подключаться надо под именем `apache@localhost`, а вам, судя по содержимому вопроса, требуется изменить это имя на `root@localhost`. хотя подключаться под именем *root* я бы не рекомендовал: лучше создать непривилегированного пользователя, которому дать необходимые права на используемую базу данных.

Comment: Да в том то и дело, что нету там настроек подключений через apache, на другом сервере все ок..

Comment: Все оказалось проще, просто другой конфиг, перекрывал тот, который я настроил, и пытался подключится без логина и пароля. Спасибо)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Другой конфиг, перекрывал тот, который я настроил, т.е. на самом деле подключение происходило без логина и пароля.